JQuery $(window).height() incorrect after window maximized then restored to original size
I have a function that uses window height to set a bootstrapTable's height.  In addition, I'm using a resize event listener to change the height of the table if the window is resized.
This is inside an electron project on a windows machine.
This is the first part of the code which is triggered when a button is clicked:
  var $table = $("#results-table");
  var $availableHeight =
    $(window).height() -
    $("#results-header").outerHeight(true) -
    $("#search-section").outerHeight(true) -
    50;

  $table
  .bootstrapTable("destroy")
  .bootstrapTable({ data: data, height: $availableHeight });

If I log the window height to console I get a window height of 835px which is correct and the table is sized as I expect.
This is the same code within a window resize event listener:
window.addEventListener("resize", function (event) {
  var $table = $("#results-table");
  var $tableData = $table.bootstrapTable("getData");
  var $availableHeight =
    $(window).height() -
    $("#results-header").outerHeight(true) -
    $("#search-section").outerHeight(true) -
    50;

  $table
    .bootstrapTable("destroy")
    .bootstrapTable({ data: $tableData, height: $availableHeight });
});

If I maximize the window the table resizes correctly.  Unfortunately when I restore the window back to its original size (by clicking the min/max button again) and log window height to console it now shows as 818px even though the window size has not actually changed (it is still has a height of 835px).  This causes my table to be slightly shorter than it was originally.
I haven't been able to figure out why this is happening.

Try these approaches:

Debounce Resize:
let resizeTimeout;
window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  clearTimeout(resizeTimeout);
  resizeTimeout = setTimeout(resizeTable, 100);
});

function resizeTable() {
  // Your table resizing code here
}


Use document.documentElement.clientHeight instead of $(window).height() for stable height measurements.

Electron Resize Workaround: Use Electron’s BrowserWindow API to get accurate dimensions on resize.



Thanks for the suggestions.  Options 1 & 2 both yield the same incorrect results (818px vs 835px).  Oddly, window.innerHeight consistently returned 835px so that's my solution

Using setTimeout to get window height after rendering completed, $(window).height(), and document.documentElement.clientHeight all return the same inconsistent results (835px after the window is initiated and 818px after it's been maximized/restored to the original size).
window.innerHeight consistently returned 835px so that was my solution.
